# Executing grunt through node

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs

I'm building a node application that requires me to run grunt on a directory to build a "package". I'm using Node's `exec` command to execute grunt like so:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('grunt', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Grunt task completed');
    }
});
```

Which triggers the below error and I'm not sure why...? (or what it means)

```
{ [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c grunt
] killed: false, code: 2, signal: null, cmd: '/bin/sh -c grunt' }
```

I'm running this on OSX but the application will be deployed to a server running Amazon Linux.

Update:

```
exec('/bin/sh -c grunt', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error) console.log(error);
});
```

Outputs the below error (but works fine when ran from terminal):

```
{ [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c /bin/sh -c grunt
]
  killed: false,
  code: 2,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/bin/sh -c /bin/sh -c grunt' }
```

Comment: Try running `/bin/sh -c grunt` and show us the output of that.

Comment: @simplyianm modified post